# Load immediate Floating Point in ARM Register

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I need to load the immediate value 0.5f ( = 0.8 in HEX) in a NEON register (or an ARM register, than i can VMOV it) using assembly.

I've read ARM doc: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/Bcfjicfj.html
Which links to: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/CIHGGEEB.html

Where they say you can load floating point:

> Any number that can be expressed as +/-n * 2-r, where n and r are integers, 16 <= n <= 31, 0 <= r <= 7.

Because 0.8 is out of range, I'm expecting i need to load HEX 1.8 and subtract 1.0 but the following instructions are not OK for the compiler:

```
VMOV.F32 d10, #0x1.0 \n\t
VMOV.F32 d10, #0x1.8 \n\t
```

However using the 0.5 decimal value does the trick, even if it should be out of range:

```
VMOV.F32 d10, #0.5 \n\t
```

Using HEX values how can i do the same operation?

Also another question: the previous VMOV.F32 instruction is expected to load the value in both 32 bit parts of the register d10[0] and d10[1] or not?

Comment: 0.5 is in an expressible immediate value.  What makes you think it isn’t?

Comment: In my project i'm expressing every immediate in HEX, for consistency i would like to express 0.5 in HEX.

Comment: It sounds like your compiler doesn’t support hex fp immediates.  I’m not surprised; I don’t know of many that do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.5` is exactly `+16*(2^-5)` (n=16, r=5, note that it's not 2-r in the manual, it's 2 raised to -r) , so it's an ok value to move.

In other words, 0x0.8 should work too (although I can't test that very assembler, hex float syntax varies)

The manual also says;

> imm is a constant of the type specified by datatype. This is replicated to fill the destination register.

which, as I read it, would fill the whole (both parts) of the register.

Comment: 0x0.8 causes a "garbage following instruction..." compiler error.

Comment: @AlessandroGaietta [This page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/Babjhibj.html) claims that the only hex floating point format is raw format, that is, not decimal but "bit pattern". In other words, `0x0.8` is an invalid value, since the supported hex formats don't have decimal points.